# Apache Iceberg Scheme Evolution using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

Currently I am using Iceberg in my project, so I am having one doubt in that.

My Current Scenario:

1. I have loaded the data into my Iceberg table using spark data frame(this is my doing through spark job)

   ```
   df.writeTo("catalog.mydb.test2").using("iceberg").create()
   ```
2. Now From source side I have added two colums and started the Job which is doing merge

   ```
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("myview")
   spark.sql("MERGE INTO catalog.mydb.test2 as t USING (SELECT * FROM myview) as s ON t.id = s.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET * WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ")
   ```

Doing both of these step I am expecting new columns to be added into the target table but it did not work.

As I can see Iceberg Support full schema evolution.. What does it means..if it is not adding any columns dynamically to my target table.

Please help how can I achieve adding new columns into my target table dynmically.

Comment: https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-ddl/#spark-ddl

Comment: Iceberg lets you **manage** the schema evolution, but it won't do it for you. It doesn't make sense to add columns 'dynamically'; even though it might be convenient in some cases, in most cases it can cause unmanageable catastrophes. You need to explicitly add new columns to your tables.

Comment: You can use Spark SQL for it:
`ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD COLUMN <column_name> <column_type>`

Answer (score 2):

You can enable this with `merge-schema` option, but we don't recommend it because, as @shay__ points out, it can sometimes cause unmanageable catastrophes.

Comment: where do we add this option exactly, it would be a great help if you can tell a few of the unmanageable catastrophes. Because if the use case is a table should accept incoming data even if a few columns are missing or there are extra columns, this should be a good solution, isn't it?